# Where is CakePHP client side form validation?

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP automatically does some client side form validation for me - checking whether a field is empty or if an email field is actually an email address. Incorrect fields get a nice little dropdown with an error message.

Where is this managed? I want to add this sort of validation to my confirm_email field.

Comment: It's actually a mix of Cake and your browser, the browser will trigger HTML5 validation if a variety of tags are added (http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation)

CakePHP's form helper simply facilitates the addition of these based on your database

Comment: Validation rules are set on every <Model>Table.php

Answer (score 1):

$this->Form->input('textfield',array('required'=>true));

will do some HTMLrequired field

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're talking about [HTML5 Form Validation](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/).

In this case you could see such dropdowns because of attributes like `required="required"` and `type="email"` in your inputs.

Validations could be managed inside `src/Model/Table/SomeTable.php` files. See example below for `UsersTable.php`.

```
class UsersTable extends Table {

public function validationDefault(\Cake\Validation\Validator $validator) {
    $validator->add('email', [
        'email' => [
            'rule' => array('email', true),
            'message' => __('Please, set valid email address')
        ]
    ])
    ->add('password', [
        'length' => [
            'rule' => ['minLength', '8'],
            'message' => __('Password must have at least 8 characters'),
        ]
    ])
    ->add('password_confirmation', [
        'length' => [
            'rule' => ['minLength', '8'],
            'message' => __('Password must have at least 8 characters')
        ],
        'compare' => [
            'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password'],
            'message' => __('Passwords should be the same'),
        ]
    ])
    return $validator;
}

}
```

Please pay attention on `password` and `password_confirmation`. You could solve your problem similarly using rule `compareWith`.

See also official documentation about [validations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html).

Comment: You're right. I was referring to HTML5 Form Validation. I was able to add an email validator with the following Javascript.

    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var confirm_email = document.getElementById("confirm-email");
    function validateEmail(){
        if(email.value != confirm_email.value) {
            confirm_email.setCustomValidity("Emails Don't Match");
        } else {
            confirm_email.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
    confirm_email.onchange = validateEmail;

Comment: Oh I see. For front-end validation I'll suggest to use something like [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/#validators-equality). There is a validator named `equality` which could be used to verify that one input value is equal to another. Here is an [example](https://validatejs.org/examples.html) how it works.